# Why the global variables in mysql.pm is not declared as our?

Tags: perl, variables

Quoted from `mysql.pm`:

```
   3 package DBD::mysql;
   4 use strict;
   。。。。
  17 $err = 0;>--# holds error code   for DBI::err
  18 $errstr = "";>--# holds error string for DBI::errstr
  19 $drh = undef;>--# holds driver handle once initialised
```

What's strange is that all my programe that `use warnings;` and uses this module doesn't give any warnings.

Why?

Comment: `use warnings;` is lexical.  The code nevertheless does not produce warnings, but that is for the benefit of -w

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On line 5 of the source:

```
use vars qw(@ISA $VERSION $err $errstr $drh);
```

See [use vars](http://perldoc.perl.org/vars.html) documentation.

It's one of the ways we were able to make globals and strict coexist before `our` was introduced to Perl.  Though it's now considered "obsolete" (according to the documentation), it still exists in real code.  I guess in some cases it fits into the category, "If it's not broken, don't fix it."  You found one of those cases.

Comment: `use vars` and `our` have subtly different behaviors, and blindly changing `use vars` to `our` without planning for this can cause hidden bugs.

Comment: I don't see anything in my post that was intended to give the impression that one should blindly change `use vars` to `our`, but for those who still haven't read the documentation on use vars, and our, Ven'Tatsu's point is valid.  This is probably why DBI hasn't been changed; it's not broken, don't fix it..... because the two are not identical in their behavior and we don't want to break anything else.

Answer (score 6):

These variables are pre-declared with the [`vars`](http://perldoc.perl.org/vars.html) pragma on the 5th line:

```
use vars qw(@ISA $VERSION $err $errstr $drh);
```

That's why Perl doesn't complain despite `use strict` being in effect.